# Best way to force delete a file in my project?

Tags: java, file

I am trying to force delete a file if it is open. From my searches here i found that the best/only way to do this is through command line.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c taskkill /f /im myFile.txt");
```

I also need to get the full file name for my file which is kept inside the project. For example my myFile.txt file is stored directly in the project directory. I want to find a way to reference it's full path. Another post on SE said that

```
getClass().getResource("myFile.txt")
```

Can give me the full path such that i can use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c taskkill /f /im " + getClass().getResource("myFile.txt"));
```

to delete my file, but this isn't working.

Comment: Why do you need to force-delete it?  Is it locked by another process?

Comment: How do you create the file?

Comment: @SteveSmith in case it's open in the OS, not by something else in my program. victor, i create the file with new File("myFile.txt")

Comment: How is the OS opening it?  Is there another program?

Comment: It's a file that the user might view but i want the program to close it if it's open so it can rewrite the file.